# CSS transition in combination with JS clickEvent

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

Encountering the following issue when trying to combine `CSS` transitions with `JS` event handlers. I know how to use CSS transition property for example:

```css
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    transition: width 2s;
}

div:hover {
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I also know how to put a click handler on an `DOM` element like this:

```js
let eventDiv = document.querySelector('#clickMe');
let hiddenDiv = document.querySelector('#hiddenDiv');

eventDiv.onclick = () => {
  if(hiddenDiv.style.display === 'block') {
    hiddenDiv.style.display = 'none'
  } else{
  hiddenDiv.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

```css
#clickMe{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#hiddenDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="clickMe"></div>
<div id="hiddenDiv"></div>
```

### Question

How do I combine the two and get a `CSS` transition (`<div>` should not appear immediately but should slide in) when I toggle the visibility of the `<div>` with a `JS` onclick event?

Comment: you need to add and remove a class that changes the property with a transition on

Comment: You cannot transition `display`.

Comment: display properties are not animatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, to combine the js and transition, you need to add and remove a class that changes the property that you want to transition.

In the below snippet, I add and remove a class of hide, which changes the height (that has a trnasition on it)

```js
let eventDiv = document.getElementById('clickMe');
let hiddenDiv = document.getElementById('hiddenDiv');

eventDiv.onclick = () => {
  if(hiddenDiv.classList.contains("hide")) {
    hiddenDiv.classList.remove("hide");
  } else{
    hiddenDiv.classList.add("hide");
  }
}
```

```css
#clickMe{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#hiddenDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow:hidden;    
  transition: height 1s;
}

#hiddenDiv.hide {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="clickMe"></div>
<div id="hiddenDiv" class="hide"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you cannot give `transition` to `display` property:

```css
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    transition: 2s;
}

div:hover {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

What you can do is to use `opacity` instead.

```js
let eventDiv = document.querySelector('#clickMe');
let hiddenDiv = document.querySelector('#hiddenDiv');

eventDiv.onclick = () => {
  if(hiddenDiv.style.opacity === '1') {
    hiddenDiv.style.opacity = '0'
  } else{
  hiddenDiv.style.opacity = '1';
    }
}
```

```css
#clickMe{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#hiddenDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="clickMe"></div>
<div id="hiddenDiv"></div>
```

**IMPORTANT**
If you choose to use this property remember to change `display` to `none` after the transition is over if you don't want it to be `block`.