# How do I make a sliding transition with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a transition that, when the button is clicked, reveals a section of the page that is hidden. The think is, I want it all to happen within the div with the border. 
For this example, I want the `<a>` tag to be shown when I click the button. Also, when I click it, I want both the button and the text to slide to the left, being replaced with the tag.

Here's what I have so far:

```css
.testparent {
  margin-left: 35%;
}

.test {
  border: 0.5px solid silver;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 999;
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 0.5px solid silver;
  height: 40px;
  outline: none;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  width: 65px;
  display: block;
}

button:focus {
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateX(-75px);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="testparent">
    <div class="test">
      <button id="button1">Test</button><br>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu omnium equidem quo, id primis nostro atomorum his. Ad mel facer dicam. Ad vix stet perpetua, ex omnes referrentur vel. Sed te omnes doming, mea ea prima iracundia. Eruditi recteque an cum.</span>
      <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html
```

I've tried using z-index, but to no avail.

Comment: So, what did you try? Plenty of sliding examples here on SO. Just try searching your own tittle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS transition in combination with JS clickEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49301316/css-transition-in-combination-with-js-clickevent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this question is tagged with JavaScript, I figured a JS solution should be acceptable.

By giving the *test* `<div>` an **ID**, you can target this directly with JS.

Using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) with the **click** trigger, whenever the element with the ID of **click-me** is clicked, the class **active** will be added or removed to/from the content and link, by using the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) toggle method.

By setting the initial **transform** of the elements you wish to remain outside the container before click to `translate(-100%,0)` will move the elements to the left and outside of the container. You may need to play around with the numbers if using this with different sized container with elements that are not 100% width.

By adding `overflow: hidden;` to the *test* container, you can make sure that any content that would appear outside of the element, will be hidden.

You can do away with the button if you wish as it doesn't do anything in this implementation.

```js
let clickable = document.querySelector( "#click-me" );
let content = document.querySelector( "#content" );
let link = document.querySelector( "#link" );

clickable.addEventListener( "click", function() {
  
  content.classList.toggle( "active" );
  link.classList.toggle( "active" );
  
});
```

```css
.testparent {
  margin-left: 35%;
}

.test {
  border: 0.5px solid silver;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 0.5px solid silver;
  height: 40px;
  outline: none;
  width: 65px;
}

#content,
#link {
  transition: transform .8s ease;
}

#link {
  transform: translate(-100%,0);
  display: block;
}

#content.active {
  transform: translate(-100%,0);
}
#link.active {
  transform: translate(0,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="testparent">

  <div id="click-me" class="test">
  
    <div id="content">
    
      <button id="button1">Test</button><br>

      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu omnium equidem quo, id primis nostro atomorum his. Ad mel facer dicam. Ad vix stet perpetua, ex omnes referrentur vel. Sed te omnes doming, mea ea prima iracundia. Eruditi recteque an cum.</span>
      
    </div>
  
    <a id="link" href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
  
  </div>
  
</div>
```

[Here's some further reading regarding the CSS transform property.](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/)